# How to use subst in linux through ant script?

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, build, ant

Below is the ant script I am using to map a network drive in windows.

```
<exec dir="${basedir}" executable="cmd">
          <arg value="/c"/>
          <arg value="subst X: ${vobDir}"/>
        </exec>
```

How to replicate the below command when running the ant script in linux?

From comments:

I am doing below task through ant in windows.

```
<delete file="X:\CalcMgrADFUI\CalcMgrUI\ojdeploy.log" quiet="true"/>
<exec dir="${basedir}/CalcMgrUI" executable="cmd">             <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value="${ojdeploy} -buildfile X:\CalcMgrADFUI\CalcMgrUI\calcmgr-ojdeploy-build.xml -clean -forcerewrite -statuslogfile  X:\CalcMgrADFUI\build-status.log>ojdeploy.log 2>&amp;1"/>
</exec>
```

Now I have to call this ant script in Linux box. So trying to make it compatible with linux

Comment: That doesn't map a network drive, you're giving a drive letter to a directory.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst

Comment: Since Linux does not have drive letters... what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am doing below task through ant in windows.```<delete file="X:\CalcMgrADFUI\CalcMgrUI\ojdeploy.log" quiet="true"/>
        <exec dir="${basedir}/CalcMgrUI" executable="cmd">
          <arg value="/c"/>
          <arg value="${ojdeploy} -buildfile X:\CalcMgrADFUI\CalcMgrUI\calcmgr-ojdeploy-build.xml -clean -forcerewrite -statuslogfile  X:\CalcMgrADFUI\build-status.log>ojdeploy.log 2>&amp;1"/>
        </exec>``` Now I have to call this ant script in Linux box. So trying to make it compatible with linux

Comment: I am not sure if I can call this script ignoring the steps that are used to Map to a network drive

Comment: So you're actually just using that "X:" as an alias / shortcut to your directory defined earlier. I don't know ant, but to me it looks like you could just use ${vobDir} instead of X: